# Applescript write text file to a folder that contains backslash

Tags: path, applescript

I am trying to write a text file to a folder named folder_01/01/2000

My code is the following:

```
set folder_path to " >> ~/Desktop/folder_01/01/2000"
do shell script "echo " & "text" & folder_path & "textfile" & ".txt"
```

I get an error saying that the directory doesn't exist. I believe that is happening because I have backslashes in the name of the folder and it meshes up the the path.

When I remove the backslashes it works properly.

Is there a way to write to the folder with the backslashes?

Comment: That are not backslashes but slashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @vadian stated, you ought not to used slashes (`/`) in your file and folder names, for this very reason.  It not only confuses you as a user, but it can confuse a shell, which can lead to anomalous or catastrophic results during file processing.

But, to answer your question, the way to reference that folder in your script is to replace the slashes (`/`) in the folder name with colons (`:`):

```
set folder_path to " >> ~/Desktop/folder_01:01:2000/"
do shell script "echo " & "text" & folder_path & "textfile" & ".txt"
```

(**PS.** You also omitted a slash at the end of the folder name, which is needed to form part of the path to the text file.  I've inserted it above.)

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about slashes (`/`) not backslashes (`\`).

Slashes are path separators in macOS. You are discouraged from using slashes in file names